# Calculating Rolling Mean of Temperature Anomalies- python

Tags: python, pandas, moving-average

The data set is indexed by year-month-day (dates) and has columns TMAX and TMIN.

I need to calculate rolling means of each of the anomalies you calculated. Use a window of 10 years and have the window centered, then add this to your plot.

This part of the code creates a plot of anomalies:

```
tmaxanom = cll.TMAX - cll.TMAX.mean()
tminanom = cll.TMIN - cll.TMIN.mean()
yearlytmax = tmaxanom.resample('1y').mean()
yearlytmin = tminanom.resample('1y').mean()
ax = plt.plot(yearlytmax, color='red', lw=2, ms=3, marker='o')
ax = plt.plot(yearlytmin, color='blue', lw=2, ms=3, marker='o')
plt.legend(('TMAX Anomaly', 'TMIN Anomaly'), loc='best')
plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Degrees C")
plt.title("Temperature Anomalies in College Station, Texas")
```

I am trying to calculate rolling means by the following:

```
rolmean = yearlytmax.rolling(window=10, center=True)
rolmean2 = yearlytmin.rolling(window=10, center=True)
plt.plot(rolmean, color='pink', label='Rolling Mean Max')
plt.plot(rolmean2, color='yellow', label='Rolling Mean Min')
```

However this is causing python to throw an error: NotImplementedError: See issue #11704 https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11704

I followed the link, however am still unsure how to fix this problem.

A Sample of data is:

`DATE       TMAX.   TMIN
1951-08-01  37.8    22.8
1951-08-02  37.8    22.2
1951-08-03  40.0    23.9
1951-08-04  41.7    26.7
1951-08-05  41.1    26.1
1951-08-06  40.6    26.7
1951-08-07  38.9    24.4
1951-08-08  39.4    25.0
1951-08-09  38.9    24.4
1951-08-10  38.9    24.4
1951-08-11  38.9    22.2
1951-08-12  40.0    23.3
1951-08-13  40.6    22.8
1951-08-14  41.1    25.6
1951-08-15  41.1    23.9
1951-08-16  42.2    24.4
1951-08-17  41.7    24.4
1951-08-18  36.7    21.7
1951-08-19  31.7    23.3
1951-08-20  36.7    21.7
1951-08-21  38.3    23.3
1951-08-22  39.4    22.2
1951-08-23  37.2    23.9
1951-08-24  37.8    23.3
1951-08-25  38.3    23.9
1951-08-26  37.8    23.3
1951-08-27  37.8    23.9
1951-08-28  38.3    22.8
1951-08-29  38.3    23.3
1951-08-30  38.9    23.9
... ... ...`

Comment: Please provide sample data so we can figure out the issue. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you don't mind doing it by hand, it should be pretty easy to do by taking the mean of a `[window_center - 5: window_center + 5]` type of list.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding in `.mean()` to the end of each of the rolling mean commands, so it looks like:

```
rolmean = yearlytmax.rolling(window=10, center=True).mean()
rolmean2 = yearlytmin.rolling(window=10, center=True).mean()
```